# is the var flightPlanCoordinates = [{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},{lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821}]; an array or an object?

Tags: javascript

I've read some forums that says the following and it seems right.

```
var foo = ["a", "b"];//is an array
var foo = {'name':'myname', 'age':'4'};//is an object
```

both in javascripts. but what happens when the curly brackets are inside the other? like the following.

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];//is this a 2-d array?
```

determining this one might help me solve why i cant use my json data and to draw a polyline in my map.

Comment: You have an array of objects.

Comment: As mentioned above, this is an array of objects. This is usually the format API requests return data (though not always). You can access the data, first by entering the array (array[0] in this case) and then using the object keys.

Comment: @Ele come on, he is confused already. Let's just say that array are objects, so tecnicnally it's an object, but since we can identify the `array` as a specific javascript type, let's just say that we're talking about an **array** of **objects** :P.

Comment: @Ele I know, and we're both aware that truth is an object as well. Anyway.

Comment: thanks everyone, finally was able to solve the problem, I was actually passing a string to the paths for goolge maps. not the object of coordinates.
had to make an object and then passing it to the array solved my problem. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Think of array as a sort of store. That store can hold a variety of things. In your example,
`var foo = ["a", "b"]` is an array of strings, because the elements of the foo array are strings. You can access them using iterators (loops, etc) or directly using the index.

`foo[0] // "a"`
`foo[1] // "b"`
`foo[2] // undefined`

Since you know that `{name: "John Doe", age: 40}` is an object, then `flightPlanCoordinates` is an array of objects. You can access the elements of that array using iterators or manually as well.

`flightPlanCoordinates[0].lat // 37.772`

Arrays can even hold other arrays as well. Wha

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an array of objects. You can access it using  `flightPlanCoordinates.forEach` or using a `for` loop. For example, the first element can be accessed like this `flightPlanCoordinates[0].lat` and `flightPlanCoordinates[0].lng`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following `foo`,`bar` and `flightPlanCoordinates`

```
var foo = ["a", "b"];
var bar = {'name':'myname', 'age':'4'};
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];
```

**LETS START HERE**

Arrays are a special type of objects , so if you use `typeof` you might get confused .

```
console.log(typeof foo); // object
console.log(typeof bar); // object
console.log(typeof flightPlanCoordinates); // object
```

But don`t worry , this is how you know if something is an array :

```
Array.isArray(foo); //returns true
Array.isArray(bar); //returns false
Array.isArray(flightPlanCoordinates); //returns true
```

This is how you loop through arrays

```
foo.map((x)=>{
    console.log(x); //do something with the items in an array
});


flightPlanCoordinates.map((x)=>{
    console.log(`Latitude : ${x.lat} , Longitude : x.lng `); 
    //do something with the items in an array
});
```

For reference :

[this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) talks about arrays .

[this article](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isarray.asp) talks about the Array.isArray() method.

[this article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/es6-map-vs-object-what-and-when-b80621932373) talks about the .map() method.

I hope I have assisted you , thanks.